# GridLayout columnCount does not work in non-Holo theme

Tags: android, grid-layout

Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.calculatorsample.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<EditText
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button android:text="&lt;-" >
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="CE" >
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="C" >
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="+/-" >
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="√" >
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="7" />

    <Button android:text="8" />

    <Button android:text="9" />

    <Button android:text="/" />

    <Button android:text="%" />

    <Button android:text="4" />

    <Button android:text="5" />

    <Button android:text="6" />

    <Button android:text="*" />

    <Button android:text="1/x" />

    <Button android:text="1" />

    <Button android:text="2" />

    <Button android:text="3" />

    <Button android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:text="=" />

    <Button
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button android:text="." />

    <Button android:text="+" />
</GridLayout>
```

This works fine when Theme is set to Holo both on the actual device (I'm on a Nexus 5 but I'm guessing this is not a device-specific issue) and on the eclipse preview. But when I set the activity's theme to anything else -- both on the eclipse preview and on the manifest, it looks bad. Screenshots below:

**Non-Holo looks like this**
[image: Non-holo]
**Holo looks like this**
[image: Holo]

I don't want (or rather, can't) use Holo since I'm already using the new ActionBarActivity that requires a Theme.Appcompat theme to work.

I'm more interested in knowing why this is the GridLayout's behavior rather than a possible workaround with the Holo thing.

Additional Info:

In Holo theme, when I increment the columnCount of GridLayout, the cell widths adjust properly. In other themes, they just extend from the screen.

I've tested on an actual device. Looks exactly as in the preview mode.

Comment: Looks like you have the same problem even with holo theme. Look at the other screen sizes. Try setting widths for your buttons...?

Comment: Better use `TableLayout`

Comment: @ElefantPhace are you proposing I set a fixed width for the buttons, or some sort of fill_parent/wrap_content setting? It's probably possible to solve this with some screen width vs number of columns trick programmatically, but I think that defeats the purpose of a GridLayout.

Answer (score -2):

Use `TableLayout` with `TableRow`'s for your layout. It works great!

Comment: How do you think should I go about implementing the equals button (referring to the screenshot) spanning two rows?

Comment: you cant implement equal with table layout